# TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача состоит в том, чтобы отобрать уникальные объекты из массива, и сделать их нижнего регистра. На шаге, когда я привел массив в одну строку и поменял регистр, все хорошо, но когда я добавляю отбор уникальных объектов терминал выдает: TypeError: tre.reduce is not a function

```
var names = ['web', 'interner', 'JavaScript', 'Internet', 'script', 'programming'];
var tre = names.join().toLowerCase();
var uniq = tre.reduce(function(a,b){
if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
return a;
},[]);

console.log(uniq);
```

Comment: а что вы имеете ввиду под обьектом ? Ну и `reduce` метод масива, а вы его применяете к строке, изза этого ошибка

Comment: под объектом имеется ввиду слова в массиве

Comment: вам надо создать массив слов в нижнем регистре, используйте для этого функцию `map`

Comment: что-то не получается, как правильно это прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Описание метода `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var names = ['web', 'interner', 'InterneR', 'JavaScript', 'Internet', 'script', 'programming'];
// создаем новый массив, в котором будут все те же значения, только в нижнем регистре
var tre = names.map(function(e) {
  return e.toLowerCase();
});

var uniq = tre.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(uniq);
```

Comment: cпасибо, работает!